# Python multiprocessing while loop, return and append outputs

Tags: while-loop, multiprocessing, return

I have a conceptually simple code I want to parallelize, but all the other threads I found about are too complicated and I do not understand how to apply them to my case, or even if they are applicable.

In my code, a function with multiple arguments is called over a while loop and returns both an output and the exit condition from the loop. I want to parallelize the while loop. I am using Python 3.7.3.

Here is a simplified example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time

def foo(i, arg1, arg2):
    n = np.random.rand()
    n = arg1*n + arg2
    if n > 0.9:
        stop = True
    else:
        stop = False
    return [i, n], stop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 0
    stop = False
    output = list()
    while not stop:
        out, stop = foo(i, 1, 0)
        i = i + 1
        if not stop:
            output.append(out)
    print(np.asarray(output))
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.          0.25295033]
 [ 1.          0.53795096]
 [ 2.          0.48774803]
 [ 3.          0.09281972]
 [ 4.          0.75053227]
 [ 5.          0.30367072]
 [ 6.          0.57043762]
 [ 7.          0.4589554 ]
 [ 8.          0.33231446]
 [ 9.          0.76805717]
 [10.          0.22486246]
 [11.          0.69499273]
 [12.          0.67616563]]
```

EDIT. I would like to "bump" this thread as this is something I really need help about and I cannot do it by myself. Meta-etiquette says I should edit by adding value to the question, but I do not think I could add anything else: I just need to parallelize the code presented. I would really appreciate any (practical) feedback.